# Find all sequential rows with the same value

Tags: r

I have a load of genomic data as follows:

```
chr   leftPos  Def
1      23444     1
1      63226    -1
1      125325   -1
2      12       -1
3      5435     -1
3      5675      0
3      67868     0
3      78999     0
4      3465      1
5      67868     1
5      78979     1
5      80988    -1
```

For each $chr I would like to get all rows where the row above has the same entry in $Def as the row below in a separate dataframe, retaining both rows of the match. The entry in $Def can be either -1, 0 or 1 but I'm not interested in 0.

I'm not bothered about what happens at the very end and beginning of the $chr so that can be ignored.

I guess this is going to be done in some kind of lapply but I have no idea how.

The output should look something like:

```
chr    leftPos    Def
1      63226    -1
1      125325   -1
5      67868     1
5      78979     1
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: Please provide a bit more complex example.  The expected result we can get from `subset(df1, !is.na(Def)& Def!=0, select= c('chr', 'leftPos', 'Def' ))`

Comment: I have amended the dataset

Comment: I updated the solution.  Please check if that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df2)`), create an 'ind' column based on run-length type id.  Grouped by 'chr' and 'ind', create a logical condition for 'i', `if` the nrow is greater than 1, we Subset the Data.table (`.SD`), and assign the 'ind' to 'NULL'.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
setDT(df1)[, ind:= rleid(Def)][!is.na(Def)&Def!=0, if(.N>1) .SD, .(chr, ind)]
#   chr leftPos Def
#1:   1   63226  -1
#2:   1  125325  -1
#3:   5   67868   1
#4:   5   78979   1
```

Comment: The problem is that if I remove the NAs  and 0s before processing then I create a false continuity between the rows I am interested in. I want to find continuity for only 1 and -1 as it lies in the origins dataframes by chr.  However if I omit the subset ting them I get all the continuous na and zero which is no good. What about running the setDT like for just continuous 1s and then for continuous -1s and then merging ?

Comment: @SebastianZeki Can you update with some NA elements along with a similar example I showed in the comments so that we can test for all those cases.

Comment: @SebastianZeki  I updated the post.  Please check if that works.